# text and checkbox on one line within a table cell, bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what my table looks like right now:

[image]

I want the checkbox to be on the right of "CMPT 310" instead of below it. I can't simply make the text a label for the checkbox because when I click on the text I want a description of the course to pop up (ie I don't want to checkbox to be checked). Here is how I'm implementing the problem cell in the table right now (using bootstrap):

```
                <td>
                        <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CMPT310">CMPT 310</p> 
                        <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="">
                        </div>                                              
                </td>
```

And here is the rest of the page for reference:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12"><img src="images/title.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <h4><strong>Table I: Computing Science Concentrations<strong></h4>
  </div>  
  <table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Artificial Intelligence</th>
     <th>Computer Graphics</th>
     <th>Computing Systems</th>
     <th>Information Systems</th>
     <th>Programming Languages and Software</th>
     <th>Theoretical Computing Science</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
       <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CMPT310">CMPT 310</p> 
       <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">
         </div>            
     </td>
     <td>CMPT 361</td>
     <td><strong>CMPT 300</strong></td>
     <td>CMPT 301</td>
     <td>CMPT 373</td>
     <td><strong>CMPT 307</strong></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>  
 </div>


 <!-- START MODALS -->


 <!-- CMPT 310-->
   <div class="modal fade" id="CMPT310" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/cmpt310.png">
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>         
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `p` and `checkbox` inside the `td` element to be displayed inline.

```
td p,
td .checkbox {
  display: inline;
}

td .checkbox {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```css
td p,
td .checkbox {
  display: inline;
}
td .checkbox {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="images/title.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h4><strong>Table I: Computing Science Concentrations<strong></h4>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Artificial Intelligence</th>
          <th>Computer Graphics</th>
          <th>Computing Systems</th>
          <th>Information Systems</th>
          <th>Programming Languages and Software</th>
          <th>Theoretical Computing Science</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CMPT310">CMPT 310</p>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>CMPT 361</td>
          <td><strong>CMPT 300</strong>
          </td>
          <td>CMPT 301</td>
          <td>CMPT 373</td>
          <td><strong>CMPT 307</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


  <!-- START MODALS -->


  <!-- CMPT 310-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="CMPT310" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="images/cmpt310.png">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That almost did it, thanks! However, now the checkbox and the text aren't horizontally aligned (the checkbox is slightly higher). Is there an easy fix for that?

Comment: I played around with padding and got it.

Comment: Can you explain the td p, td . checkbox syntax? What does it mean in English?

Comment: Yes, it means that you are targeting the paragraph and checkbox inside every td element. Got it? :)

Comment: So the second rule targets every checkbox within a td element? For the first rule, what's the purpose of the second td? To specify that we're targeting the paragraph and checkbox inside every td element I would expect to see one td, one p, and one checkbox.

Comment: Actually, if you have time to help me troubleshoot one more thing, I thought that I had fixed the padding problem by adding "padding-top: 4px" directly below "margin-left: 5px" but that doesn't seem to do what I want. I can get it to behave properly by styling it explicitly in the html, but I've heard that's bad form.

Comment: I used the second rule because it would avoid `margin-left: 5px;` for the paragraph elements inside td. Please check this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048 Descendent selector

Comment: Adam, I have edited your code to align it horizontally. Is this what you needed?

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! Thanks so much Manoj!

Comment: I guess my problem was that I was missing the position: absolute.

Comment: Welcome, Alex! :) Yes because the new element inline was taking the relative space.